# what's the meaning of "time-tagged"

Tags: meaning

i don't understand the meaning of "time-tagged"

e.g.
The event data is encoded into time-tagged actions (assault, kidnap,flee, assassinate)

Comment: I would assume it means the action has a specific time associated with it, but it is impossible to know without additional context. Is this data from a video game? Tactical plan? Crime blotter?

Answer (score 1):

A bit more context would be useful, but it sounds as though each of the events has a date and time associated with it. The datetime on which it occurred (or is to occur) is recorded along with the event itself. In a database context that would likely be a column [like this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/datetime.html).

Answer (score 1):

My guess would be that by *time-tagged* the person means [*time-stamped*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timestamp) (Wikipedia): a time or a time & date is associated with the action/event/occurrence.